# Any rules that I need to follow if I want to read the Bhagavad Gita?

Tags: gods, bhagavad-gita, philosophy, life, superstitions

If I want to start reading the Bhagavad Gita. What rules, if any, that I need to follow before I start reading? For example:

1. Do I need to perform any religious rituals before reading the Gita?
2. Can I read/recite it at any time? Or are some portions of the day prohibited for recital?
3. Can I read it anywhere I want to i.e., is the place where I recite the Gita also important?

Comment: Not aware of any time, location, action related restrictions so far for Gita. The main point is that you should read the **correct translation**. ISKCON's translation is quite misleading, but the Sanskrit meanings below the verses can be helpful. Gitapress translations are little better at times. So far, I haven't come across any accurate, unbiased, neutral translation of Gita; although there could be few. Always good to have Sanskrit dictionary handy. *Personal advice*: If you feel an urge to change the way of life *because of* Gita, then something has gone wrong. Re-read it. Keep open mind.

Comment: @BarunPratiher Your question is answered here: http://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/5404/how-to-start-reading-bhagavad-gita

Comment: It is a commonly-held belief that the parayana must not start with Arjuna Vishada Yoga but has to start with a different chapter.

Comment: During any Vedic Parayana a minimum sanctity is compulsory.Even the same is true in case of reading any other Holy scriptures like the Puranas.So you should adhere to those  basic rules of sanctity(regarding urself and the place of recital) at the least if u want to recite LOUDLY(u didn't specify if u wanna read silently in mind or u wanna recite loudly ,a silent recital of a mantra stotra or any holy scripts  can be done with a impure body but not the loud recital))...regarding the other few points u've raised i have no idea

Comment: I'm sorry but I have to post this. Any rules that you have to follow if you want to read the Bhagavad Gita? Yes, Panini.